# Carrier humidifier hookup

Tags: humidifier, carrier

I had a blower replaced.  In doing so, the technician pulled the wiring for the humidifier.  The image shows the black wire is in place, the white wire not showing in the image is not wired in.  Where do I wire it in to?

[image]